# Can't save or read shared preferences in Android service

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-service

Doesn't work saving or reading shared preferences in my service. Could you suggest any workarounds?

Write:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());


    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();        
    for (PagerTagGattClient deviceGatt : this){
        set.add(getBluetoothDevice().getAddress());         
    }

    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(PREF_DEVICES, set);
    return editor.commit();
```

Read in service onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
prefs.getStringSet(PREF_DEVICES, set);

if (set.isEmpty()) Log.e(TAG, "Prefs is empty!");
```

Reading set is always empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually assign the values you read to your variable `set`:

Change

```
prefs.getStringSet(PREF_DEVICES, set);
```

to

```
set = prefs.getStringSet(PREF_DEVICES, set);
```

The second parameter is the default value which is an empty `HashSet` in your case (you can leave it this way or change to an appropriate default value).

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 editor.putStringSet(PREF_DEVICES, set);
editor.commit();
```

and while reading use

```
set = prefs.getStringSet(PREF_DEVICES, set);
```